# How to code Search result page in HTML5

Tags: html, search

I'm trying to find the best way to code a search result page in HTML5.

Here's how I've done it.

```
<section>

  <header>
    <h2>Results for <kbd>this terms</kbd></h2>
  </header>

  <!-- list of results -->
  <ol>

    <!-- First result -->
    <li>
      <article>
        <header>
          <h3>
            <cite>
              <a href="http://addressofthepage.ch/">This is a result</a>
            </cite>
          </h3>
        </header>
        <blockquote cite="http://addressofthepage.ch/">
          <p>So, setting about it as methodically as men might smoke out a wasps' nest, the Martians spread this strange stifling vapour over the Londonward country. The horns of the crescent slowly moved apart, until at last they formed a line from Hanwell to Coombe and Malden. All night through their destructive tubes advanced.</p>
          <footer>
            <p>Published <time datetime="2010-07-15T13:15:05-02:00">MMMM DDth, YYYY</time> at the <abbr title="Uniform Resource Locator">URL</abbr> <a href="http://addressofthepage.ch/">http://addressofthepage.ch/</a></p>
          </footer>
        </blockquote>
      </article>
    </li>

    <!-- Second result ... and so on -->
    <li>...</li>

  </ol>  
</section>
```

### The main questions are

1. `<header>` mentions the search terms. What is the best tag to use? `<kbd>`?
2. Is the `<cite>` tag related to the `<blockquote>` if it is positioned in the `<header>`?
3. Is not better to put the `<cite>` in `blockquote > footer` like `<p>[...] at the URL <cite><a href="http://addressofthepage.ch/">http://addressofthepage.ch/</a></cite></p>`

*All this is also available on a [Gist](http://git.io/TZ31RA)*

Answer (score 0):

1. is meant as a way to show keys. That's why many sites style that tag as a keyboard key. You're not showing keys, you're showing a search term. A `<span>` should be fine. Maybe add a class like `<span class="search-term">`.
2. Semantically speaking, no, it wouldn't be related as it's not a child.
3. The "correct" HTML for using cite and blockquote would be:

   > A quote here...
   >
   > — [Foo Bar](http://link-to-source.com)

gist here of the HTML: https://gist.github.com/OscarGodson/5a3e87ce895b3af952de (stackoverflow appears to have issues rendering HTML when in code tags?!)

Notice the cite and footer tags. As per spec:

> The blockquote element represents content that is quoted from another
>   source, optionally with a citation which must be within a footer or
>   cite element, and optionally with in-line changes such as annotations
>   and abbreviations. Content inside a blockquote other than citations
>   and in-line changes must be quoted from another source, whose address,
>   if it has one, may be cited in the cite attribute.

Source: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#the-blockquote-element

The main thing to remember, and coming from someone who's been doing this for a long, long time, semantics matter, but don't overthink it. Sure, the blockquote has some strict rules about how to properly use it, but browsers will handle whatever you give it fine. Do what makes sense for your app and that should be semantic enough 90% of the time as long as everything isn't a span and div. If you over analyze this stuff you'll spend more time deciding which tag to use instead of just getting stuff done ;)